# Set default reminder pattern to iCal Calendar/Group

Tags: macos, calendar.app

I have in iCal some Calendars/Groups named Birthday, Exams and Holidays. Now I am wondering if I can assign a default reminder pattern to all Exams events, for example:

*2 Weeks before, 1 Week before, 2 Days before.*

The result should be that I don't have to specify each time the reminder pattern of an event in Exams when I create a New one.

NOTE: If iCal can't do this, is it maybe possible do that through an automator action etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within iCal itself - no it's not possible. My recommendation would be that you could copy and paste and then change the details on a previous exam as a workaround however. (That way you don't have to re-enter the alarm details)

While possible with Automator you'd need to create a custom Automator action as the default action only permits one alarm.